# Need to press submit twice for submitting a form with ajax (jquery validation plugin)

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, callback, form-submit

The form is validated before submit with [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) plugin. And submitted as shown in the code:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   submitHandler: function(){ 
      jQuery("form").submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          jQuery.post(base_url + "blog/ajax_comment", { author: jQuery("#author").val(), email: jQuery("#email").val(), url: jQuery("#url").val(), message: jQuery("#message").val() , post_ID: jQuery("#post_ID").val(), not: jQuery("#not").val() }, function (data) {
             //do stuff here
          });
      });
  }
});

jQuery().ready(function() {
   // validate the comment form when it is submitted
   jQuery("#commentform").validate();
});
```

In order to be submitted, I need to press the submit button **twice**. I am kind of new to jQuery, and I can't really tell why is that. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `submitHandler` is already overriding the default event, so just place the code for the ajax submission in there:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function(){ 
    jQuery.post(base_url + "blog/ajax_comment", { author: jQuery("#author").val(), email: jQuery("#email").val(), url: jQuery("#url").val(), message: jQuery("#message").val() , post_ID: jQuery("#post_ID").val(), not: jQuery("#not").val() }, function (data) {
      //do stuff here
    });
  }
});
```

If you elements have `name` attributes that match their IDs though, just use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), like this:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function(form){ 
    jQuery.post(base_url + "blog/ajax_comment", jQuery(form).serialize(), function (data) {
      //do stuff here
    });
  }
});
```

---

What's happening with your *current* code is that in the `submit` handler, it's **attaching** a *new* `submit` handler for *next* time, rather than actually running your code.  Instead, just run your code directly in the `submitHandler` callback.