# Suddenly my form submit button only works after having being clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm not sure why. I think it started when I incorportated jQuery's .validator.

The website: http://friendswithwheels.herokuapp.com

The javascript:

```
$('#newLender').validate({
    rules: {
        fee: { 
            required: true,
            number: true,   
        },
        email: { 
            required: true, 
            isYaleEmailAddress: true,
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error , element) {
        error.addClass("errorMessage");
        error.insertAfter(element);
    },


    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $('#newLender').submit( ajaxPostForLenders ); //ajaxPostForLenders submits the request
    }
});
```

Comment: It's nice if you include which of the two forms people are supposed to be testing as well as what valid entry criteria are. Works fine for me btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846930/need-to-press-submit-twice-for-submitting-a-form-with-ajax-jquery-validation-pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question here will answer your question:

[Need to press submit twice for submitting a form with ajax (jquery validation plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846930/need-to-press-submit-twice-for-submitting-a-form-with-ajax-jquery-validation-pl)

I am not going to copy and paste their answer as it's their work. But, feel free to accept my answer.

Cheers

Matt